# make downloads go to second display

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I have two displays and I generally use the browser on the left (or primary display), so I'd like any downloads (or actually any icons created on desktop) to go to the second desktop by default, is there any way I can achieve this?

I'm running windows 7 ultimate x64

Answer (score 1):

Stardock [Fences](http://www.stardock.com/products/fences/) program has a feature that allows you to create a rectangle border on the desktop in which you can store the files.

Also, would it be sufficient to open an Explorer window of the Desktop on the second screen (and keep the window opened)? You could switch to thumbnails view if you want to move the icons.

You could also use [Dexpot](http://dexpot.de/intro_en.html) and define a rule to always open new windows on the second monitor.

Comment: +1 for Fences.  Note that you may have to buy Fences Pro (not very expensive, IMO) to be able to pick a default container for new icons.